# phpMyAdmin with no privileges

Tags: phpmyadmin

Installed Zend Server CE and also installed phpMyAdmin.  When trying to login into phpMyAdmin, I can only login with the password being blank.

When in, I cannot create any databases or pretty much anything else. There is a 'No Privileges' with a red x.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the configuration (config.inc.php) and set a user with more permissions. The syntax is pretty simple and well documented.

See also this link: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

I had logged in phpmyadmin with username "admin" and password left blank.

This was showing me "no privileges" after logging in.

So, I logged out, and checked config.inc.php. Where I found the username as "root". So I logged in as "root" this time. And now it allowed me to create the database.